# convert xml to json and force element into array

Tags: javascript

from this xml:

```
<pazienti type="array">
<paziente type="Paziente">
<pz-ds-cognome>COGNOME</pz-ds-cognome>
<pz-ds-nome>NOME</pz-ds-nome>
</paziente>
</pazienti>
```

using this javascript:

```
// Function to convert XML -> JSON
function convertXmlToJson(xml) {
  const parser = new xml2js.Parser({ explicitArray: false, ignoreAttrs: true });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   parser.parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      const pazienti = result.pazienti;

      if (pazienti && pazienti.paziente && !Array.isArray(pazienti.paziente)) {
        pazienti.paziente = [pazienti.paziente];
      }
      resolve(result);
    }
});
```

});
}

when there are more "pazienti" it works fine, when there is only one "paziente" i get:

```
"pazienti": {"paziente": {"pz-ds-cognome": "COGNOME.","pz-ds-nome": "NOME"}}
```

I would like to get:

```
"pazienti": { "paziente":[{"pz-ds-cognome": "COGNOME.","pz-ds-nome": "NOME"}]}
```

Otherwise when there are more "pazienti":

```
"pazienti": { "paziente":[{"pz-ds-cognome": "COGNOME1.","pz-ds-nome": "NOME1"},
                          {"pz-ds-cognome": "COGNOME2.","pz-ds-nome": "NOME2"}]}
```

Comment: When I run your code I get your desired result.  `{"pazienti":{"paziente":[{"pz-ds-cognome":"COGNOME","pz-ds-nome":"NOME"}]}}`

Comment: Yes you are right! I didn't realize that the json I got from the ws was different from the one written here. Now I fixed it! thanks for your answer!